# How to play the high quality video when using UIWebView to load youtube video?

Tags: video, youtube

I use this code to load video from youtube

```
@implementation ViewController
 - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSString *EmbedCode = @"<iframe width=\"265\" height=\"140\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/Hwz4z5AqGuE\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
    [[self Webview] loadHTMLString:EmbedCode baseURL:nil];
    }
    @end
```

But when I debug on my device, it always load the lowest quality in spite of that video on youtube support HQ. Is there any way to allow user to choose higher quality when they play the video
?